# Spring RestTemplate Statuscodeexception pass custom message to exception handling

Tags: java, spring, rest, exception, resttemplate

In my app Service A communicates with service B.
in Service B I do some db queries so there can come up a NOT_FOUND status.

Code:

Service A

```
try{
RestTemplate.exchange()...
}catch(HttpStatusCodeException e){

return new ResonseEntity<String>(// Here custom message of service B extracted from e //,e.getStatusCode)
}
```

Service B:

```
return new ResponseEntity<String> ("My Error Message", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
```

So basically I want to use "My Error Message" in the exceptionhandling in Service A. Is there a way to pass it to the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HttpStatusCodeException` inherits a method called `getResponseBodyAsString` simply use `e.getResponseBodyAsString()` and you will get the custom message sent by Service B.

Comment: Thank you very much. Exactly what I was looking for